# What happens to the multiple attack penalty if I use a readied action to step out of melee range?

Tags: actions, pathfinder-2e, readied-action, multiple-attack-penalty

Under [this video](https://youtu.be/ni9wq4oKzhk) and in various groups, there is a debate about what happens after a character uses a readied action to step out of melee range. I did not find an official answer, so maybe you guys can help satisfy my curiosity.

I think it can be summarized to three possible outcomes:

1. The attack misses and the attacker has a penalty on the next attack
2. The action is wasted since there's no valid target, but the attacker has no penalty
3. The action is not taken since there's no valid target and the attacker has no penalty

I don't know if any of these are the correct answer.

Comment: I wonder if the person who came up with this had played Exalted, because disrupting enemy multiattacks was such a fundamental part of the optimized combat metagame in its second edition, that my first impulse reading this was to think that this a question about that game instead, until I read the question tags.

Comment: @ESCE I’m not sure that new tag is a useful tag.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov maybe, maybe not, I could see it either way, but one of the subtexts to this question is "Does a disrupted attack action still incur MAP" which is covered by the last part of Ifusaso's answer, which should be helpful to future searchers (in the much more likely case that, say, an attack spell gets disrupted by a crit on Attack of Opportunity).

Comment: @ESCE I haven't thought too much about it since PF2e isnt really my space, but one immediate concern I had about the tag was that it might act as a "tag tax" where every question that has [multiple-attack-penalty] necessarily must also have [multiattack].

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Ahhhh yeah, I can see how that'd be confusing. Definitely not the case for PF2e. To make a crude 5e analogy, think of a fighter that uses Action Surge. They are making multiple attacks in their turn, but not as part of the same attack action. This is in contrast to a monk, say, that spends Ki on Flurry of Blows to get that second punch in. The monk case is a multiattack, while the first is just... multiple attacks. In PF2e, MAP applies to some multiattacks and all multiple attacks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Frame challenge: You cannot use the "start of an attack" as a valid trigger for Ready.

[Ready in the Gamemastery Guide](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=843) has this important line to aid in adjudicating valid triggers for [Ready](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=82):

> Notably, the trigger must be **something that happens in the game world** and is observable by the character rather than a rules concept that doesn’t exist in world

In order to reach this situation, you have to [Step](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=87) (or use some other movement) in response to an enemy *starting* to attack you, but that's only a definable point in game-logic. Take, for instance, [this video on how to do a roundhouse kick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0WcFxtKFj8). The first step is to, well, step. So does every step count at the start of a roundhouse kick? What if the person is just stepping into a more aggressive position? It's not actually clear when an attack starts, especially if one wants to differentiate between an attack and a feint.

It's further clear that we are already not reacting to game world events by the shear amount of meta-game confusion this stunt causes, as demonstrated by your question. Even the video you linked expresses a fair amount of uncertainty at whether this stunt actually works, shown by the many hedged statements and their repeated insistence at "needing to see what happens in the narrative".

Yes, this is technically in the realm of GM fiat, and perhaps your GM will declare it as a valid trigger. But at that point, you just do what the GM says, and there is no RAW (nor even RAI, I would argue) guidance left. Option 3 seems the only one that doesn't result in rampant abuse of this stunt, if that is the case, and what I would recommend as a (house) rule to any GM who wishes to allow the stunt.

Note: there are many reactions in the game which have mechanical triggers. Ready simply isn't allowed to use those, and must be described in non-game language.

Note 2: [Nimble Dodge](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=550) already fills the narrative space for this kind of action (dodging out of the way of an attack at the last minute). You may also be interested in [Reactive Shield](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=360&ArchLevel=4) if you are looking for reactions of this nature.

Comment: I think *most of the time* it's clear when a person is about to attack you, especially if they're not doing martial arts for show. Although I would definitely say the Reaction triggers on a successful Feint.

Comment: @Ifusaso Historical European Martial Arts (sword, dagger etc) teaches people not to telegraph an attack. And yes, there is a word for showing you are about to attack. Wushu – same. From what I heard it's all the same in every martial tradition, with exception of capoeira that telegraphs all the time no matter if it's an attack or not. **It is not for show**. Telegraphed attacks do not hit. So we don't do it. It is that simple.

Comment: @Mołot Fair, but this is also an RPG where characters regularly do very stupid things that work (at most tables). Also, avoiding telegraphing is a very technical skill thing that not all combatants are capable of (at their skill level), and even as they grow in skill it's still near/impossible to completely achieve it when fighting an enemy trained to a similar skill level.

Comment: @Ifusaso I think also that a D&D mechanics attack is not supposed to represent every potentially threatening movement of an opponent's weapon towards you that happens in the narrative, it's an abstraction that makes the ebb and flow of real fighting manageable as a turn-taking game. You normally get one "attack" per turn, which I conceptualise as one decent opening to strike on average in the amount of time represented by a turn. To **get** that opening there would be feints and blocks, changes of position, etc. How does a character know which movement is the start of a "real attack"?

Comment: Doesn't the existence of the linked Nimble Dodge counter this answer? The Trigger of "A creature targets you with an attack and you can see the attacker." shows that Triggers can be exactly like what they want to Ready for.

Comment: @brandon - see my first note. Nimble Dodge uses an explicitly mechanical trigger, which Ready is forbidden from doing.

Comment: To be clear, I agree with this position insofar as it's a GM's call whether or not being targeted by a Strike is a viable trigger... but I think a lot or possibly even a majority of tables would allow it. Because of that, I wouldn't call this answer accurate.

Comment: @ESCE I wouldn't consider Nimble Dodge's trigger explicitly mechanical, especially because the creature attacking has to be seen by you matching the requirements quoted from the GMG.

Comment: @brandon It's the "targets you with an attack" part that is mechanical. The bulk of this answer details why I think that's a mechanical phrase, and not one with a narrative analog, thus making it an invalid trigger for Ready. (Being targeted with an attack is basically the same thing as an enemy starting an attack against you.) I agree that seeing a creature is fine as a narrative trigger and would be a fine and valid trigger for Ready.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion, but I do not see how anyone could abuse it even if worked like option 1. Giving up __2 actions _and_ a reaction__ to avoid the best MAP is a bad idea mechanically.

Comment: @András it's not just avoiding the best MAP, it's stepping out of their reach; it's essentially spending 2 actions and a reaction to waste two of the enemy's actions (one on the whiffed strike, another to step back into reach). That can be incredibly potent; combine it with a Slow spell and it makes it functionally impossible for the enemy to actually ever attack.

Comment: Good point about the step, I missed that

Answer (score 4):

The [Ready](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=82) Activity allows you to perform a [Reaction](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=442) - this is important to know for parsing the correct rules because the Reaction is what interacts with the attacker's Strike.

The question becomes two-fold, relating to the [Disrupting Actions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=394) rules.

---

1. Does the Ready Action Step *disrupt* the attack?

This is *startlingly* uncovered by the [Encounter](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=429) rules. Nothing indicates what happens when a target stops being valid.

- Spell [Targets](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=289) comes close, explaining that effects "fail to target" invalid creatures (with no definition of what that entails).
- [Range and Reach](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=352) defines Reach but doesn't mention targets moving out of Reach

***I am inclined to say* that when a creature uses a Reaction to become an invalid target, the action was already *started and is disrupted*** *unless* there is another valid target within Reach/Range (ruling that your Reaction prevents targeting you, not the entire Strike).

However, based on [Move Actions that Trigger Reactions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=446), I think it's unclear whether this is the ruling is even correct; applying the rules relating to Reacting to Move actions that don't Move you (such as Stand), the Reaction isn't resolved until after the effect. In such a case, you would Step after their first Strike, potentially preventing further attacks. I feel like that rule in more specific and not applicable to the situation above.

---

2. If so, does MAP apply to *disrupted* attacks?

Disrupting Actions:

> When an action is disrupted, **you still use the actions or reactions you committed** and you still expend any costs, but the action’s effects don’t occur.

Multiple Attack Penalty:

> If you use an action with the attack trait more than once on the same turn, your attacks after the first take a penalty called a multiple attack penalty.

**Yes, Multiple Attack Penalty is applied on disrupted attacks**, such as those disrupted by a movement Reaction.